expression must have class type but it has type "(Game (*)()"
I'm having an error at:
//Game loop
while (game.running()) {
    //Update

    //Render

}

it gives me the error: "expression must have class type but it has type '(Game (*)()'" for "game.running," and to me, everything looks correct. I included all my code below if anyone wants to look through it and pinpoint the problem. Also, please don't tell me how to optimize the code, I know it sucks, but I just want to figure this out. Thanks!
//THIS IS THE "Game.h" FILE!!!
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>

using namespace sf;
using namespace std;

/*
    Class that acts as the game engine.
    Wrapper class.
*/


class Game {
private:
    //Variables
    //Window
    RenderWindow* window;
    VideoMode videoMode;
    Event ev;

    //Private Functions
    void initVariables();
    void initWindow();
public:
    //Constructors / Destructors
    Game();
    virtual ~Game();

    //Accessors
    const bool running() const;

    //Functions
    void update();
    void render();
};
//THIS IS THE "Game.cpp" FILE!!!
#include "Game.h"

//Private functions
void Game::initVariables() {
    this->window = nullptr;

}
void Game::initWindow() {

    this->videoMode.width = 1280;
    this->videoMode.height = 720;

    this->window = new RenderWindow(this->videoMode, "Cannoneer", Style::Titlebar | Style::Close);
}

//Constructors / Destructors
Game::Game() {
    this->initVariables();
    this->initWindow();
}

Game::~Game() {
    delete this->window;
}

//Accessors
const bool Game::running() const
{
    return this->window->isOpen();
}

//Functions
void Game::update() {

}

void Game::render() {

}

//THIS IS THE "main.cpp" FILE!!!

#include "Game.h"

int main() {
    //Initialize game engine
    Game game();

    //Game loop
    while (game.running()) {
        //Update

        //Render

    }

    //End of application
    return 0;
}

Only stuff I tried was searching Google and Stack Overflow.

Game game(); -> Game game;

The comment above has the right answer, but consider enabling warnings if not yet enabled - I tried your code with GCC and got a helpful warning that suggested the correct solution as part of the error message ("note: remove parentheses to default-initialize a variable").

"I included all my code below if anyone wants to look through it and pinpoint the problem." All of your code is undesirable. Your question should have a [mre] -- keep removing code as long as the error persists. Once you're at the point where removing anything else will remove the error, you've hit a minimal example. In this case, the definition of your class should go down to class Game { bool running() const { return true; } }; and your main function... well, that actually looks pretty good already, so good job on that.
